# Google AdWords API [OperationAccessDenied.ADD_OPERATION_NOT_PERMITTED @ class campaignmgmt.campaign.MutateAction (ADD) requires CREATE_CAMPAIGN]

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api

Adding a new campaign get the following error:
**[OperationAccessDenied.ADD_OPERATION_NOT_PERMITTED @ class campaignmgmt.campaign.MutateAction (ADD) requires CREATE_CAMPAIGN]**

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue by using the client ID rather than the Manager ID.

- **Client Id** is the one in the top left corner next to

> {My Client Centre Logo} AccountName (Client Id: 123456789)

- **Manager Id**: is the one in the top right corner just above your email address

> Manager Id: 987654321
>   email.address@gmail.com

Comment: you just saved my life. +1. have been stuck on this issue for the past couple of hours.

Comment: Note: client id is a string and can be passed like `'012-545-6789'` just like it is in the web console.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it setting the campaignService->clientCustomerId.
Google AdWords account manages several client accounts with several campaigns. 
It is necessary to set the clientCustomerId in the campaignService to add a new Campaign.

My c# code:

```
// Get the CampaignService.
CampaignService campaignService =
    (CampaignService)_user.GetService(AdWordsService.v201409.CampaignService);

// Set ClientCustomerId
campaignService.RequestHeader.clientCustomerId = myClientCustomerId;
```